# Bubblesort printing out in reverse order

Tags: c#

I've written a bubblesort, however, when I print out the array, it's sorted, but it starts off with the highest number, and ends with the lowest number.

```
public int[] BubbleSort(int[] unsortedArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < unsortedArray.Length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < unsortedArray.Length; j++)
            if(unsortedArray[i] < unsortedArray[j])
            {
                int temp = unsortedArray[i];
                unsortedArray[i] = unsortedArray[j];
                unsortedArray[j] = temp;
            }
    return unsortedArray;
}
```

Could anybody explain why the list is reversed.

EDIT: Sorry, pasted the wrong code.

When the line reads
    if(unsortedArray[i] < unsortedArray[j])
the list is orderded from lower to higher, however, this logically doesn't make sense. if i is lower than j, swap them.

Comment: If `i` is less than `j`, you're replacing i with j, aka the higher number.

Comment: And I guess it would be cheating to say `var sorted = unsortedArray.OrderBy(x=>x);`?

Comment: I'm left speechless, and for a few minutes, unable to type.  If you have written a code which reverse sorts an array of numbers surely it is as obvious to you as it is to us that somewhere you have made a simple error such as `>` where you should have `<` or swapping `i` for `j` where you should have swapped `j` for `i`.

Comment: Because you're sorting it backward (from highest to lowest). Reverse your test in the `if` block (`if (unsortedArray[j] > unsortedArray[i])`.

Comment: @KenWhite, you reversed it twice.  You switched the conditional and you switched j/i

Comment: @gb1986 I added an edit to my answer with an explanation.

Comment: @Javalsu: Yep, you're right. :-) I did. S/B 'if (unsortedArray[j] < unsortedArray[i])` or 'if (unsortedArray[i] > unsortedArray[j])`, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably better as:

```
public int[] BubbleSort(int[] unsortedArray)
{
    return unsortedArray.OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray();
}
```

A few issues with the original, `i` and `j` are iterating too much, it will still work, but it's doing unnecessary iterations that won't affect the outcome, also your conditional `unsortedArray[i] < unsortedArray[j]` was backwards.

```
public int[] BubbleSort(int[] unsortedArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < unsortedArray.Length-1; i++)
        for(int j = i+1; j < unsortedArray.Length; j++)
            if(unsortedArray[i] > unsortedArray[j])
            {
                int temp = unsortedArray[i];
                unsortedArray[i] = unsortedArray[j];
                unsortedArray[j] = temp;
            }
    return unsortedArray;
}
```

Optimized bubble sort:

```
public int[] BubbleSort(int[] unsortedArray)
{
    var n=unsortedArray.Length;
    while(n>0)
    {
        var newn=0;
        for(var i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
        {
            if(unsortedArray[i-1]>unsortedArray[i])
            {
                var temp = unsortedArray[i];
                unsortedArray[i] = unsortedArray[i-1];
                unsortedArray[i-1] = temp;
                newn=i;
            }
        }
        n=newn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `OrderBy`, but I assume not using a bubble sort defeats the purpose.

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of OrderBy, my bad.  And yes, OrderBy actually does a quick sort, not a bubble sort.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thanks, rob. Unfortunately I worded the initial question incorrectly and I seem to have been 'jumped upon' because of it. Your code works fine, but could you tell me why you set the length to "Length-1" on the outer loop, but not the inner, and also, what is the purpose of i+1?

Comment: Let's say you have a 10 element array numbered 0-9.  On the first loop, i will be 0, while j iterates 1 to 9.  At the end of that first i loop, the first element (0) will contain the smallest element since it's compared every other element (1-9) and swapped it into place.  Since you now know it has the smallest element, you no longer have to check it.  Now on the second i loop, i will be 1, and you only need to compare it to the remaining elements (2-9).  I stop iterating i at 8 because at that point, elements 0-8 are the 9 smallest elements, and the 10th element (index 9) MUST be the largest

Comment: I added an optimized bubble sort which was converted from pseudo code on wikipedia to C#, I haven't tested it, but I suspect it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

it's this conditional

```
if(unsortedArray[i] < unsortedArray[j])
```

it should be

```
if(unsortedArray[j] < unsortedArray[i])
```

Edit: to answer your edit.

You want the element in `unsortedArray[i]` to have the lowest value after the inner loop is run.  Which means you only switch it out if you encounter a `unsortedArray[j]`, that's less than the current value sitting in `unsortedArray[i]`.

If `unsortedArray[i]` is already the lower value, then leave it where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your compare in

```
 if(unsortedArray[i] < unsortedArray[j])
```

should be

```
 if(unsortedArray[i] > unsortedArray[j])
```

Comment: But Why?  That was the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] bd = new int[] { 25, 35, 104, 30, 89, 30, 42, 11, 8, 4, 55, 65, 98, 542, 2 };

for (int rnd = bd.Length; rnd > 0; rnd--)
{
    for (int i = bd.Length - 1 ; i >= 0;  i--)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            if (bd[i - 1] < bd[i])
            {
                temp = bd[i];
                bd[i] = bd[i - 1];
                bd[i - 1] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j <= bd.Length - 1; j++)
{
    Console.Write(bd[j] + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Code-only answers aren't encouraged, as they don't provide much information for future readers. Please provide some explanation to the code you have written.